# Can't display my ArrayList

Tags: java, android, xml, arraylist

Currently new in Java.
I have this code where I'm want to store XML parse data for ListView. But when I try to display the content of my ArrayList in the logcat, it give me this `com.example.azrie.dummyvoice.FeedItem@717d5c6` instead. Did I not store the data properly or is there else wrong ? Can someone enlighten me on this matter.

This is my parse method

```
 public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
    int event;
    String text=null;

    try {
        event = myParser.getEventType();
        FeedItem item = new FeedItem();

        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagName = myParser.getName();

            switch (event){

                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if(tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                        int eventChild = myParser.next();

                            while(eventChild != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                                String tagNameChild = myParser.getName();

                                switch (eventChild){

                                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                                        break;

                                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                                        text = myParser.getText();
                                        break;

                                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                                        if(tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                                            item.setTitle(text);
                                            feedItems.add(item);
                                            Log.d("Title", item.getTitle());
                                        }

                                        else if(tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                                            item.setLink(text);
                                            feedItems.add(item);
                                            Log.d("Link", item.getLink());
                                        }

                                        else if(tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("description")){

                                            String plain = Html.fromHtml(text).toString();
                                            //stripHtml(text);
                                            item.setDescription(plain);
                                            feedItems.add(item);
                                            Log.d("Description", item.getDescription());
                                        }

                                        else if(tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")){
                                            item.setPubDate(text);
                                            feedItems.add(item);
                                            Log.d("pubDate", item.getPubDate());
                                            //Log.d("pudDate",text);
                                        }

                                        else if(tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail") || tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("media:content") || tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("enclosure")){

                                            //Output test
                                            if(myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"url") != null) {
                                                item.setThumbnailUrl(text);
                                                feedItems.add(item);
                                                Log.d("Thumbnail", item.getThumbnailUrl());
                                                //Log.d("ItemThumbnailUrl",myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"url"));
                                            }
                                        }

                                        else if(tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                                            Log.d("Test", "" + feedItems.get(1));

                                        }


                                        break;



                                }

                                eventChild = myParser.next();
                                /*feedItems.add(item);
                                Log.d("Title", item.getTitle());
                                Log.d("Link", item.getLink());
                                Log.d("Description", item.getDescription());
                                Log.d("pubDate", item.getPubDate());
                                Log.d("Thumbnail", item.getThumbnailUrl());*/

                            }


                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    break;

            }

            event = myParser.next();

        }

        parsingComplete = false;
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you using for your adapter?  It looks like you passed it an array of FeedItems where it expected strings.

Comment: What is given to you ... is a call to toString() on a class that doesn't implement toString(), so you get the default implementation from java.lang.Object that simply prints the "reference" for each object. And side note on code quality: don't push so much code into **one** method. Please read about "clean code", and "single layer of abstraction" for example. Basically, what you wrote up there is **hard** to test; and worse: it will turn into a maintenance nightmare soon. Yes, making things work is important, but writing code that can be understood is even more important!

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you. I know where I went wrong now. This is just a tutorial that I followed online. I'll make sure to read it.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
com.example.azrie.dummyvoice.FeedItem@717d5c6
```

indicates that you are logging (or printing) an object and not a string.
I would guess that this originate from this line:

```
Log.d("Test", "" + feedItems.get(1));
```

Try to implement toString method on the FeedItem class. Or if that's not possible try something like

```
Log.d("Test", "" + feedItems.get(1).getTitle());
```